# How to get rid of bed head

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have had bed head for a while now, and I can't get to go away. I have tried looking for a comb and standing in the rain to wet it, but this hasn't worked. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to remove bedhead is to go to Shampoodle, a hair salon in the city, and get a new haircut for 3,000 Bells. Bedhead can be hidden with a hat, wig, or Mii Mask, though some hats do not cover all hair. Some hats can cover all of the Player's bedhead,e.g. hero's hat.

[Source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bedhead)

Answer (score 1):

According to [nookipedia](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Bed_head),

> To remove bed head, the player will have to go to Shampoodle and get a new haircut. The player will have to spend 3,000 Bells to get a new haircut, but if the player does not, villagers may comment on the players hair. Bed head can happen to anyone, regardless of hair color or hair style. Bed head will overwrite any other hairstyle the player has.